# Find the period of occurence of a value in table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with the following data.

```
+------------+---------+
|   Date     | Version |
+------------+---------+
| 1/10/2019  |       1 |
| ....       |         |
| 15/10/2019 |       1 |
| 16/10/2019 |       2 |
| ....       |         |
| 26/10/2019 |       2 |
| 27/10/2019 |       1 |
| ....       |         |
| 30/10/2019 |       1 |
+------------+---------+
```

I need to find the period of occurrence for **version** in the table.
Eg:Suppose I need to get Version 1 occurence details which is present from 1/10/2019 to 15/10/2019 and from 27/10/2019 to 30/10/2019. How can i query the database for such a result?
I have tried many ways but not able to produce the desired result .I even doubt this is possible using a query!
Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Expected output:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| Version | Period from |  Period To  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
|       1 | 1/10/2019   | 15/10/2019  |
|       2 | 16/10/2019  | 26/10/2019  |
|       1 | 27/10/2019  | 30/10/2019  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: please provide expected output

Comment: @Mazhar added the expected output table

Comment: `version` 3 doesn't exist in the sample data?

Comment: Sorry! it was version 1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Redshift is the one !!

Answer (score 0):

This is gaps and Islands question.

Try this

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE ( [Date] DATE, [Version] INT)

INSERT INTO @SampleData ([Date], [Version])
VALUES
    ('01-10-2019', 1), ('02-10-2019', 1), ('15-10-2019', 1),
    ('16-10-2019', 2), ('17-10-2019', 2),('26-10-2019', 2),
    ('27-10-2019', 1), ('28-10-2019', 1), ('30-10-2019', 1)


SELECT
    Y.[Version]
    ,PeriodFrom = MIN(Y.[Date])
    ,PeriodTo   = MAX(Y.[Date])
FROM(
    SELECT 
        X.[Version]
        ,X.[Date]
        ,ISLAND = RN-ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY X.[Version] ORDER BY X.[Date])
    FROM(
        SELECT
             RN=ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY S.[Date])
            ,S.[Date]
            ,S.[Version]
        FROM
            @SampleData S
    ) X
) Y
GROUP BY
    Y.[Version], Y.ISLAND
ORDER BY
    PeriodFrom
```

Output

```
Version PeriodFrom  PeriodTo
1       2019-10-01  2019-10-15
2       2019-10-16  2019-10-26
1       2019-10-27  2019-10-30
```